# Would anyone be able to help name this progression?

Tags: harmony, chord-theory, chord-progressions, terminology

I've had trouble coming up with a name for this progression and was wondering if there is a jazz term or if it's a type of cadence.

Cm7 D7 Gmaj7

Comment: Cadences are generally the last two chords, so D7>Gmaj7 will be a perfect cadence (on the right of the Atlantic). As in V>I. What comes before doesn't usually affect a cadence. I guess the whole sequence would be iv>V>I, for want of a better term.

Comment: Not everything has a name. And for chord progressions, their names are usually just the names of the chords. So you’ve already named it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no name for this progression, but there is a name for the harmonic concept that it demonstrates.

These three chords point towards G major. And in G major, the seventh chord built on C is Cmaj7. But in this example, you have a Cm7.

And that's because the Cm7 is actually the seventh chord built on C in G *minor*. So this progression, very obviously written in G major, uses the C chord "borrowed" from the parallel key of G minor.

We call this Cm7 a "borrowed chord," and this progression is an example of "mode mixture" because we mix harmonies that occur between the modes of major and minor.

Comment: Weird, I actually think of this chord progression as being in **C minor** instead and the D7 chord is a secondary dominant.

Comment: @Dekkadeci - true, Cm might work, but it would be more convincing if the G was G7, rather than Gmaj7. Don't often come across Gmaj7 in key Cm. D7 as a sec.dom. works best when its F# moves directly to G, rather than stops on F#!

Answer (score 4):

It's a variation of the stock ii-V-I progression that underpins so much popular music.   If it ends a phrase, the last two chords form a perfect cadence (or whatever people call a V-I cadence in your territory).

Not everything has a precise label.  If you want to describe 'Cm7 D7 Gmaj7', say 'Cm7 D7 Gmaj7'.